# Why do I get a warning for the sudoers.d when doing an audit with Lynis?

Tags: linux, permissions, security, sudo, audit

I stumbled upon Lynis - a security auditing tool for linux - and ran it on my Raspberry Pi to see if I could harden it a bit more. I got one warning in the *Authentication* group that confuses me.

```
  - sudoers file                                              [ FOUND ]
    - Permissions for directory: /etc/sudoers.d               [ WARNING ]
    - Permissions for: /etc/sudoers                           [ OK ]
    - Permissions for: /etc/sudoers.d/010_pi-nopasswd         [ OK ]
    - Permissions for: /etc/sudoers.d/010_at-export           [ OK ]
    - Permissions for: /etc/sudoers.d/README                  [ OK ]
    - Permissions for: /etc/sudoers.d/pihole                  [ OK ]
```

However further down in the Result section it says:

```
-[ Lynis 2.7.5 Results ]-

  Great, no warnings

  Suggestions (5):
  ----------------------------
[...]
```

Also none of the *Suggestions* are referring to this Warning.

These are the permissions for the mentioned directory:

```
$ ls -l /etc/ | grep sudo
-r--r----- 1 root   root     669 Nov 13  2018 sudoers
drwxr-xr-x 2 root   root    4096 Dec 28  2018 sudoers.d/
```

Does anyone know why I get this warning and where I might find more detailed information?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Lynis [expects `/etc/sudoers.d` to be unreadable by “others”](https://github.com/CISOfy/lynis/blob/ea03723093c0394ffdd4b4003a2c807077d0d8a7/include/tests_authentication#L503), *i.e.* `rwx[r-][w-][x-]---`. If you run

```
chmod 750 /etc/sudoers.d
```

the warning will disappear.

The information should have been logged in the Lynis log file...